# How can I add a checkbox to a ListActivity and not lose onListItemClick functionality?

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity working as expected.  When a list item is clicked the app responds properly.  I want to add a checkbox on the far right side of the screen, next to each list item.  When I attempted to do that by updating the XML (see below) I lost the onListItemClick functionality.  When I clicked on a list item nothing happened.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvProduct" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:paddingRight="10sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPrice" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:paddingRight="10sp"
            android:textColor="#606060" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to add the checkbox next to the tvProduct object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a ListView has focusable (clickable) children, it loses focusablitity itself.  You can either have a checkbox (button, etc) by clickable inside of a ListView, or have the entire row be clickable.

If you are trying to allow the user to select multiple rows and show the selection state in a checkbox, you can use the [choiceMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode) CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.

Here is an [example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example/) of it in use.

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I want it to look like, but I don't think the functionality is what I'm looking for.

The user will have 3 tabs, each resulting in a ListActivity.  The first tab will consist of unchecked values, the 2nd is checked values, and the 3rd is all values.  When a checkbox is selected I want the tool to move it to the proper tab (checked or unchecked).

Answer (score 1):

In the adapter in the getview method, set the checkbox use checkbox.setFocusable(false) and checkbox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false).  You can still click the checkbox, but clicking anywhere else gets the list item.  Both work fine.

I know there was already an answer, but this has worked for me in the past and is easy to implement so I wanted to add it.